# Removing cloud cover on LandSat 8 imagery using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, landsat-8, cloud-cover

How can I remove cloud cover on landsat8 imagery? 
using ArcGis10.2

Comment: What do you mean by "remove" - show the true terrain under the cloud (thats impossible, as far as i know), or mask the cloud, so that your analysis will not try to analyze the cloud (thats what @Luke suggests using the QA band)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to go back to your imagery provider and get imagery from an earlier (or later) date which is cloud free

Mapbox provides cloud free imagery but as it is merged from lots of different photo's you can't use it for analysis and I don't know how much it costs

https://www.mapbox.com/data-platform/

Answer (score 3):

You can mask using the [Landsat 8 QA Band](http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8QualityAssessmentBand.php).  To assist with extracting values from the QA bands, USGS provides [LDOPE Tools](http://landsat.usgs.gov/L-LDOPE_Toolbelt.php).

Alternatively, you could try [FMASK](https://code.google.com/p/fmask/).