# Removing Clouds From (Landsat8) NDVI Imagery with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, ndvi, arcgis-10.5

I recently was able to generate NDVI images from Landsat 8 using Arcmap. My end goal is to run some zonal statistics over specific neighborhood polygons, however with the cloud values (ranges of 0.002< X <0.025) still in my images, this will skew my results. I've thus far tried to figure out how to remove this using raster calculator but I'm not certain I'm actually doing what I think I am.

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, how could I remove the above data range without altering the rest of my image?

Comment: Have you check suggestions in below link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130667/removing-cloud-cover-on-landsat-8-imagery-using-arcgis-for-desktop

Answer (score 0):

That specific link didn't solve my problem but it did lead me to one that did.

[Delete values from raster file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221979/delete-values-from-raster-file)

I need to figure out exactly what expression I need to get the range I want removed but it puts me right next to where I need to be. I think I just need to reverse what I've got for the formula at the moment.

```
Con(("NDVITest" < 0.025) & (0.002<="NDVITest"), "NDVITest")
```